# Diference in windows 2008 R2 editions MSDN Technet Volume License

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Are there any differences when downloading a windows 2008 R2 standard edition from different sources like:

- Volume License Platform
- Technet
- MSDN

I mean, does the one I download from technet expects more bugs than downloaded on MSDN or MOVP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server software is functionally the same for all three editions.  What makes them different is the activation model.  Technet and MSDN versions expect Technet and MSDN MAKs, respectively.  Volume Licence Platform only works with VLK MAKs or KMS (which is the default).

Comment: Great answer! THanks! VLK (Volume License Key), MAK (Multiple Activation Key) KMS (Key management service) Correct?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, as of Server 2008 R2, you can activate MSDN bits with a VL license key and vice-versa. This was not the case with Server 2003.

Comment: Rod, you are correct on the acronyms.  As far as VL key is concerned, I think Miles may be correct.  We have, however noticed that the edition type DOES matter for Office 2010 activation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most important difference is the *way* that you can use the editions.  (AFAIK) Technet is supposed to be used for "testing", MSDN for developing, and VL for production.

Thigh might be important to remember, but as far as the actual product, they should all be the same, provided it's the same version.